# multiple page turn effect like flipboard

Tags: ipad, core-animation

I want to make multiple page turn effect like flipboard. please give me suggestion How to implement this effect.

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [github.com/raweng/FlipView](https://github.com/raweng/FlipView), we tried to replicate Flipboard app for ipad !!

Implemented some of the features like

- multiple flip (just click on last pagination if u r at first or second for multi-flip).
- Views arrangement if orientation changed like Flipboard
- selection of random layout

Hope it helps u :)

Comment: It seems the link is dead. Do you know where is it possible to find it? Thanks